Movie about an odd hidden shop of wonders
It was a movie/short/series I watched either in the late 1990s or in the early 2000s. Might be older than that.
A group of teenagers stumble into a shop full of odd and maybe wondrous knick-knacks. It had all sorts of things and the shopkeeper was this old man. Maybe it was martial-arts related, I don't remember well.
I think the teenagers got something from the shop to fight some BBEG. I can't even remember if it was live-action or animation.
I know it wasn't Little Shop of Horrors with Rick Moranis and Steve Martin. That was the top Google hit when I searched.

It reminds me of a movie in which a guy was getting bullied while visiting an old Chinese guy in a shop, and then when he grabbed a staff, he got transported into a different world, and the first girl he encounters is Jackie Chan.

What bes a BBEG?

@DavidW:
Big Bad Evil Guy

@Clockwork: You're thinking of The Forbidden Kingdom I'd wager.

@FuzzyBoots And here I was contemplating a Blue Brain-Eating Gerbil.  I think I'd prefer to see my movie. :)

I vaguely remember seeing this Stephen King adaption, Needful Things - too fuzzy on details to tell if it's a match. Does have an old man with a shop selling supernatural items though.

@razethestray I think Needful Things has people buying things for themselves, not to fight monsters.

Feels like there might be some crossover with https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLittleShopThatWasntThereYesterday

@JonCuster Whoops! I meant guy

I remember Friday The 13th Series I believe that they had to go find/collect magical items that were cursed.  Or Warehouse 13 (similar concept, they found and categized weird objects that had powers, but that was more of a comedy.
